# How to keep a list of acceptable types for comparison in Chapel

Tags: chapel

Suppose I have class `Student`, `BadStudent:Student`, `GoodStudent:Student` and `ExcellentStudent: Student`. I want a class method to only operate on `Good` and `Exceptional` students.  Something like:

```
class AdvancedBasketWeaving {

  // this is the question:
  var acceptableStudentTypes: [1..2] = [GoodStudent, ExcellentStudent];

  proc accept(student: Student) {
    for at in this.acceptableStudentTypes {
      if student.type == at then return "YES!";
    }
    return "Computer says 'No'";
  }
}
```

How do I get this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two tools that I think you'll want to use for this pattern:

1) The first is Chapel's cast operator (`:`).  For classes, casting is similar to C++'s dynamic cast.  In short, given a class object like the following instance of `GoodStudent`:

```
var brian = new GoodStudent();
```

a cast of the object to a class type will return `nil` if the object is not a subclass of that class and the class reference if it is.  Thus:

```
...(brian: Student != nil)...           // will evaluate to true
...(brian: BadStudent != nil)...        // will evaluate to false
...(brian: GoodStudent != nil)...       // will evaluate to true
...(brian: ExcellentStudent != nil)...  // will evaluate to false
```

Thus, to test for a `GoodStudent` or an `ExcellentStudent`, you could write:

```
if (student:GoodStudent != nil || student:ExcellentStudent != nil) then
  return "YES!";
```

Alternatively, if every `ExcellentStudent` is also a `GoodStudent`, you might consider making it a subclass of `GoodStudent` in your class hierarchy rather than a sibling to it.  In that case, you could simply write your conditional as:

```
if student:GoodStudent != nil then return "YES!";
```

since both `GoodStudent` and `ExcellentStudent` would return true for this conditional.

As an important note, it may be tempting to simply write this conditional as:

```
if student.type == GoodStudent
```

but this would not give the correct behavior in the context of your procedure since it is declared as follows:

```
proc accept(student: Student) { ... }
```

Specifically, the `.type` query will return the static (compile-time) type of a class object, and in the context of this routine, the static type of `student` is `Student` due to its formal type.  So comparing its static type would never match `GoodStudent`, even if the object's dynamic type was `GoodStudent`.  Using the dynamic cast addresses this by changing from a static test to a dynamic one.  Another approach would be to make the `accept()` procedure completely generic, as follows:

```
proc accept(student) { ... }
```

but then you open up the floodgates by permitting other non-`Student` types to be passed in.

2) The second thing you need (and the focus of your question) is a tuple type, which is probably the best / lightest weight way to create a collection of types.  Chapel only supports arrays of values, not types, so the following line in your code is not legal:

```
var acceptableStudentTypes: [1..2] = [GoodStudent, ExcellentStudent];
```

Instead, create a tuple type to store all the types you want to compare against:

```
type acceptableStudentTypes = (GoodStudent, ExcellentStudent);
```

This leads to my suggested solution ([try it online](https://tio.run/##nZPBTsMwDIbP9Cm8XpZKaBNXph0YmrhxGRLiaFKPRcuSKkk7Ctqzl6TtWNk60OihUh37y//bLl9hRrKquERrYeHylJSDz2gXRU1ohmkbve07ftD61/P5OycpfbA/aTwGBJdnkkAvATmnzOGr/3JlRhYufqJQ1@G0lz3VtCmwjtzrE23JZK/6Li1QcUpnaNfkngkLod68YoDMaN7ymT2ylNQZAN6UcGTQeVMFGXArajwOLVjxQRcZCq@lNlcZGtyAAKHgZjTqdziq6amOmlqvwxKBWEJaKtwIjlKWwNG64Caoah2A043I0Lx4q83axqcqIJC@PfcrYCKBwRSUkAGooj3AkMuNgvhlvhjEk6gbutebLPftAoulheGjHtYJu7AeBRrgOjeW/PAUbfsHw/zgtsa3XCrWZLf9YaGklceSJJl0PfnunF59cHweePgjfjL/Dews5Q@iB4Z@nduM88Djxd5T/wBW1Rc)):

```
class Student {
}

class BadStudent: Student {
}

class GoodStudent: Student {
}

class ExcellentStudent: Student {
}

// a tuple of acceptable types                                              
type acceptableStudentTypes = (GoodStudent, ExcellentStudent);

class AdvancedBasketWeaving {
  proc accept(student: Student) {
    // iterate over the tuple's size                                        
    for param i in 1..acceptableStudentTypes.size do
      // see if dynamically casting the student to the type "works"         
      if student: acceptableStudentTypes(i) != nil then
        return "YES!";
    return "Computer says 'No'";
  }
}

var course = new AdvancedBasketWeaving();
writeln(course.accept(new Student()));            // Computer says 'No'     
writeln(course.accept(new BadStudent()));         // Computer says 'No'     
writeln(course.accept(new GoodStudent()));        // YES!                   
writeln(course.accept(new ExcellentStudent()));   // YES!
```

Note that I've moved the `acceptableStudentTypes` declaration from the class scope (which is logical and where you had it) to the module scope.  This is because of an apparent bug in Chapel which I've [filed an issue against](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/9605).

Or, if you can make `ExcellentStudent` a subclass of `GoodStudent`, I think the following is much nicer ([try it online](https://tio.run/##nZExb8IwEIV3/4oHC/FS9kYMBaFuXRhQx5NzLVFdO7KdQFXx20MSUmpolErc@O7dd093akcF67pWmrzHJpQZm4BvcRTiLC0p69XHofaztaP99UGx1o14MUUTsfEpq8gozpbkPzhsmarcvDcGoHBWgZTiIiT@ZpXsHED@Bj@0YLKAyTXCjk3nAxyH0hlMX9ebyTQVsbSyn0UZ2MHTl8fsxc46w7ENWZGDsqXzjAbJ@@G8iUzF3uWBtUnO7oc@eDvSh0qklCmims/xd/WlOwL8/c01825gdLorYgNs74XhGgHevv@H@g9Q1PUJ)):

```
class Student {
}

class BadStudent: Student {
}

class GoodStudent: Student {
}

class ExcellentStudent: GoodStudent {
}

class AdvancedBasketWeaving {
  proc accept(student: Student) {
    if student: GoodStudent != nil then
      return "YES!";
    return "Computer says 'No'";
  }
}

var course = new AdvancedBasketWeaving();
writeln(course.accept(new Student()));            // Computer says 'No'     
writeln(course.accept(new BadStudent()));         // Computer says 'No'     
writeln(course.accept(new GoodStudent()));        // YES!                   
writeln(course.accept(new ExcellentStudent()));   // YES!
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to store the types by casting them as a `string`.

For example,

```
var a = [int: string, string: string];
writeln(a);
var b = 1;
var c = "sdasas";
if b.type: string == a[1] then writeln("This matches!");
if c.type: string != a[1] then writeln("This doesn't match!");
```